# WordPress Menu Prepends URL To My Anchors

Tags: menus

I have a menu created in the WordPress menus page. It is made up of anchors created using custom links. For instance, I have a custom URL #claims which is supposed to anchor drop down to the "claims" portion of my page. However, upon saving this menu and visiting the page, WordPress prepends the URL before the anchor so the outputted href link is mydomain.com/#claims (it ignores adding the page slug). When I click on the anchor, it takes me to the home page! When I manually add the page slug into the custom link, so that it is /slug/#claims, the page refreshes and THEN drops down to the anchor. When the href is just #claims, everything works fine (I tested that by editing the href in the Chrome inspector).

I just want to click on my menu link and have it drop me down to the appropriate section without refreshing the page.

Is there a way to make WordPress avoid prepending anything in front of the anchor?